# How to integrate paypal

Tags: php, paypal

My website is for people who own bikes, offer them for rent, then clients come and book their bikes for drive.

So here is my problem with paypal.

1. Client picks bike from list and book it
2. Client confirms that everything is ok with prices and make payment on Paypal Checkout to my website Paypal business account

Problem starts here:

3. This amount of $ is not yet taken from client (for 48 hours), owner of bike should confirm it first through his account on my web.
4. When owner of boat confirms it, then payment executes and take money from clients card or paypal account

After that I pay owner his $ through my business account and that's not a problem. Those 3rd and 4th steps above are.

Is that even possible? If yes, how do i do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes. It is possible with PayPal.**

We are calling it Authorization and Capture. It is a two-step payment model. In this model, Authorization is Step 1, It is happening when the customer is completing his payment.

Capture is Step 2. It is happening when the seller has confirmed the order and he can capture the amount.

For example a client needs to book a bike a bike for 100$. When placing an order, Client will authorize(Normal paypal checkout flow, Nothing different!) 100$. The Owner of the boat get the notification,and If He is having enough boats, He will Capture(This is where amount deduction happens) the amount to proceed further.

Please get more details by following the below link,

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/

Please find the example code below

Please follow the link http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/AuthorizePaymentUsingPayPal.html

In the above example, Just note that we are setting Intent "Authorize"
Just remember, In the response you will get "authorization_id".

This is how you have to capture the payment which you authorize from your customer. 
http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/AuthorizationCapture.html

Note that they are passing "authorization_id" to capture the amount. Once the capture is done, the money will be transferred to Merchant account.